# useSelector is not updating after dispatch call and state change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I created a login component and would like to display error messages under certain circumstances.  I am making a dispatch call after the login button is pressed which triggers the onSubmit event for the form and I can see where the right switch condition is reached to update the correct state variable.  However, I am never seeing the component update after the reducer code is called.  I am calling useSelector to retrieve the new value.  Is this not how this should work?  What am I missing here?

Login component:

```
    const Login = (props) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const errorMessage = useSelector(state => state.errorMessage);
  const store = useStore();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    console.log('before');
    console.log(store);
    await dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: "This is a test" });
    console.log('after');
    console.log(store);
    debugger;
  }

  const changeUserName = (e) => setUsername(e.target.value);
  const changePassword = (e) => setPassword(e.target.value);

  return (
      <div>
        <div className="w-100">
          <Container>
            <h1 className="text-center">Login</h1>
            <Box className="card loginUI" component="form" onSubmit={submitForm}>
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="formFlexContainer">
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <TextField className="w-100" id="userName" label="Username" name="userName" onChange={changeUserName}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <TextField className="w-100" id="password" label="Password" name="password" onChange={changePassword}/>
                    <span style={{color: "#ffffff", backgroundColor: "#000000"}}>{errorMessage}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                      Login
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
};

export default Login;
```

Authentication Reducer:

```
import { AUTHENTICATE_USER, AUTHENTICATION_ERROR } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    authenticated: "",
    errorMessage: ""
};

export const authenticationReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTHENTICATION_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                authenticated: action.payload.token
            };

        case AUTHENTICATION_ERROR:
        debugger; <- ***I am seeing this line reached after the dispatch is called***
            return {
                ...state,
                errorMessage: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

store.js:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import {rootReducer} from './reducers';

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];
const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer];
const composedEnhancers = composeWithDevTools(...enhancers);

return createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers);
}
```

src/index.js:

```
import configureStore from './store.js';
const store = configureStore();
window.store = store;

debugger;
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

update:

I used getStore to get the current store and accessed it before and after the call to dispatch and I can see where the variable in the store is getting updated and changing.  Although, this adds even more confusion for why the component is not updating.

```
const store = useStore();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    console.log('before');
    console.log(store);
    await dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: "This is a test" });
    console.log('after');
    console.log(store);
    debugger;
  }
```

Comment: They are combined in the store using the rootReducers.

Comment: Are you sure you are pulling out the values correctly in the selector ? Seems like the values would be nested inside the entry for the authentication reducer in the state.

Comment: for debugging purposes, try storing `store` into window (`window.store = store`) then inspect on the console to see the hierarchy, you might be calling the wrong object.

Comment: Which file and where should I do that?  Looking at the code above.

Comment: I used useStore to get the current store and I can see where the variable is updated.

Comment: I can't imagine this is related, but just to rule it out, I notice your first reducer case is also `AUTHENTICATION_ERROR` instead of `AUTHENTICATE_USER`